# Not able to copy file from s3 bucket with speacial character in name

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have to copy the file from one s3 bucket to another. In the name of S3 bucket there are some special character which restrict it to appear as single file name. While fetching the list from bucket, we are able to get the file name but while copying, we get file not found error.(while copying,it goes to read the filename but due to special character not able to read.)

*Code I am using:*

```
def copy_object():
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=os.environ.get('bucket'), Prefix='v2/abc/date='+date)
    for s3_objects in response["Contents"]:
        key = str(s3_objects["Key"]).split("/")[4]      #this will give file name
        print(key)
        
        copy_source = {
            'Bucket': os.environ.get('bucket'),
            'Key': key
        }
        s3_dist = boto3.resource(
            service_name=os.environ.get('serviceName'),
            region_name=os.environ.get('regionName'),
            aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('awsAccessKeyId'),
            aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('awsSecretAccessKey')
        )

        ack = s3_dist.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'dest_bucket', file_to_copy)
```

Filename :`Stat@2022-12-28@nameflyer@@_1672185644223109701__i-008f78f00fd9d9bfb.parquet`

*Error getting while copy the file :*

```
{'Error': {'Code': '404', 'Message': 'Not Found'},
```

How can we read the file to copy in s3 bucket with special characters or is there any way to omit special character and read the file in bucket.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: What exactly is the output of `print(key)`?

Comment: this is the filename

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your `Prefix` to the key name:

```
key='v2/abc/date='+date + '/' + key
```

Comment: This helped. I did some tweeks in the code and added the key with prefix. This way it is able to read the file.

Comment: @Barun I thought it did not work, as you haven't accepted the answer nor commented that the answer helped. Glad it worked out anyway.